# How do I use || operator so destroy ccurs in either of 2 instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, parameters, operators, destroy

I have 2 situations where I want a relationship to be destroyed. 
1. when an active relationship is deleted
2. when a passive relationship is deleted.

At the moment each situation works on it's own. But when I try to set it up so either work at the same time I get an active record error.
It's something to do with the destroy method not being able to find the relationship for the params[:id] in both occurrences. maybe it's how i'm using the || operator?

At the moment, if I try to delete a passive relationship it works. but then if i try to delete an active one I get the active record error shown below:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RelationshipsController#destroy
Couldn't find Relationship with 'id'=1 [WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = ?]
```

If I change the code so def destroy has active before passive:

```
@relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id]) || current_user.passive_relationships.find(params[:id])
```

then the active_relationship delete works, but the passive_relationship delete returns the active record issue. (this time with:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RelationshipsController#destroy
    Couldn't find Relationship with 'id'=1 [WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = ?]
```

how do  i let it know it's ok if

```
@relationship = current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id]) || current_user.passive_relationships.find(params[:id]
```

only finds one of the relationships using the id provided?

relationships/edit: (VIEW)

```
<% if @active_relationship %>
    <% if @active_relationship.pending? %>
        <%= form_for @active_relationship, url: relationship_path(@active_relationship), method: :delete do |form| %>
        <%= submit_tag "Delete Request", class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @passive_relationship %>
    <% if @passive_relationship.pending? %>
        <%= form_for @passive_relationship, url: relationship_path(@passive_relationship), method: :delete do |form| %>
        <%= submit_tag "Decline Relationship", class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

relationship controller:

```
def destroy
    @relationship = current_user.passive_relationships.find(params[:id]) || current_user.active_relationships.find(params[:id])
    if @relationship.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Relationship destroyed"
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

Create a method in your app/models/user.rb(`User`):

```
def find_by_passive_or_active_relatioship(id)
  passive_relationships.where(id: id).first || active_relationships.where(id: id).first
end
```

then in your controller:

```
def destroy
  @relationship = current_user.find_by_passive_or_active_relatioship(params[:id])
  if @relationship.try(:destroy)
    flash[:success] = "Relationship destroyed"
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Relationship can be destroyed at the moment. Try again.'
  end
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

You can use, `find_by` method instead of `where(id: id)`, depending on your Rails version.

`find` raises `RecordNotFound` exception if it doesn't find the resource, while `where().first` or `find_by` methods don't.

Comment: and create the method in user not relationship model? I'm Rails 4+ so find_by should work